# could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETPortable,Version=v5.0" framework

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, portable-areas

I am trying to implement finger touch login in my xamarin app

for that I have installed package Plugin. Fingerprint version 1.4.5.0

but it gives me an error while building

> The primary reference "Plugin.Fingerprint, Version=1.4.5.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETPortable,Version=v5.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111".

after searching for that error I got this solution

> I've converted all projects in my Xamarin solution to netstandard1.1
>   (I used your guide) and now all works

but I m wondering it will not affect other feature of application?
 means this is the right solution? to degrade version like this will not affect any other things?

if yes what is the other solution to this error?

please help

Comment: Often higher versions keep compatibility with olders, especially when the minor version is what is changed. It generally include new features and bugs corrections.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza sorry i didnt get you.i should go with solution or not?

Comment: can you elaborate please.what exactly this .net standard version affects on pcl or any other project .and how it affects new package added for plugin.

Comment: The .net standard is the library package over which the xamarin framework runs (prior to .net core). Aparently the Fingerprint plugin 1.4.5 was built over the .net standard package, and this affects the range of Profiles that the plugin may be compatible (more information [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) and [here](https://www.danrigby.com/2014/05/14/supported-pcl-profiles-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2/)). In short, if the change doesn't affect your target, yes, you can use it.

Comment: ok.thank you for your help and time @DiegoRafaelSouza

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I accidentally installed VS 2019 on Mac. I only wanted to update VS 2017, but you have to read the changes very carefully (no hint at front that you are upgrading VS!). Then I found [a way to downgrade VS on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414654/426227) to *VisualStudioForMac-7.8.4.1*. Afterwards, I figured out that my Jenkins build (using `msbuild`) doesn't work with the above failure.

> warning MSB3274: The primary reference "Plugin.Fingerprint, Version=1.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETPortable,Version=v5.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7".

The `msbuild` version changed from *16.0.42-preview+g804bde742b* to *16.0.459+g5b35a69a2e*. Switching to `xbuild` showed me a deprecated warning as well as the Java version is not found (for Droid).

Luckily I found [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/378713/#Comment_378713), where the solution is described.

**TLDR:**

- Install the [MonoFramework-MDK-5.18.0.268 package](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/5.18.0/macos-10-universal/MonoFramework-MDK-5.18.0.268.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg) from [this site](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/5.18.0/macos-10-universal/) on the Mac.
- Check the version under *Visual Studio > Preferences > Projects > .NET Runtimes* and see if `Mono 5.18.0.268` is set as default.
- Have fun :)

Comment: This worked for me too ! I struggled a long time with this one, then I went into the prferences and picked the pevious Mono runtime (without installing something else) ... Poof it was solved !

Comment: The 5.20.x version is what I needed to switch to, and then it built. So, I feel you may need to experiment on the Mono version... I already had 5.18.x installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `Visual Studio` I think it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using these steps:

- Right click to project and select unload project(In this case you should unload
  that you want to implement).
- After that right click again and select edit.PROJECTNAME.csproj and update TargetFrameworkVersion to 4.5 
  [image]
- Right click and reload project

That was my solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and Visual Studio Mac had the hint path wrong. Newer versions of VS Mac don't appear to allow you to change the Mono version, so the advice above didn't work for me.

Here's what I had to change:

1. Right click the project and select "Edit Project File"
2. Look for the library that's causing you issues. For example:

   < Reference Include="Polly, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   ....\packages\Polly.5.1.0\lib\ **netstandard1.0** \ Polly.dll < /HintPath>

(sorry for the weird markup... the editor is NOT liking the XML for some reason)

Note that it's targeting **netstandard1.0**? Well, if it's PCL 4.5, you need to change that to the following:

```
<Reference Include="Polly, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Polly.5.1.0\lib\net45\Polly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If you look in your packages folder, you should see the **net45** folder next to the netstandard1.0 folder. As long as your packages.config pointed to the right target framework, the package should have been restored properly. However, somehow VS Mac is using the wrong hint path. I don't know if this is a bug, but I've reported it nonetheless :)