# Need lower version of visual studio for mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I just want to download a lower version of Visual Studio for Mac. The current version is 7.5.1 and I want to download 7.4.3.

Can anyone tell me where can I get that download file or link?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bunch of other versions in case someone needs them:

```
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.3.0.797.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.3.0.799.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.3.3.5.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.3.2.12.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.4.0.1033.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.4.0.839.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.3.3.5.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.4.0.884.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.4.0.985.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.4.0.1026.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.5.0.933.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.5.0.1062.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.4.1.48.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.5.0.1161.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.5.0.1244.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.5.0.1222.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview-7.6.0.711.dmg
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.8.4.1.dmg
```

**Note**: These are from the `index.xml` files that VS4M downloads that includes all the matching packages for each release

Comment: Where is the index.xml file located? Thanks

Comment: On your drive or ?

Comment: You mentioned these were from the index.xml files that VS4M downloads so wondering where that file is located. Is this something on your Mac or something you found on the web?

Comment: Please provide the entire path for index.xml

Answer (score 14):

From some guesswork I found it by using this URL :
https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-7.4.2.12.dmg

Not installed it tho.

From this, comment on the 9th May [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123413/install-previous-version-of-visual-studio-for-mac) seems like you have to open a support ticket?!?!

> As an update on this topic, all of the recent previous Xamarin.iOS,
>   Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.Mac packages are available in the
>   archives on the [open source continuous builds server](https://jenkins.xamarin.com/) (under the
>   Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.MaciOS tabs). And the Mono Framework MDK
>   is similarly available in the [Mono Project download archive](https://download.mono-project.com/archive/). I have
>   now updated the [15.7 Release Xamarin Release Blog post](https://releases.xamarin.com/release-15-7/) to provide the
>   links to those locations. In many cases, the latest version of Visual
>   Studio for Mac will be backwards compatible with previous versions of
>   the Xamarin SDKs, so you can in many cases just install those earlier
>   Xamarin SDK versions over the current versions and leave Visual Studio
>   for Mac and Mono Framework MDK at the latest.
>
> If you do need to get an older version of Visual Studio for Mac
>   itself, the best option at this time is still to create a support
>   incident to request the version you'd like. The updated info for
>   creating a Visual Studio for Mac support incident is to go to
>   Technical Support > Product: Visual Studio > Assisted Support on
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/ and then select Visual Studio
>   Community/Professional/Enterprise 2017 for Mac.
>
> I used to download previous releases from my Xamarin account page
>   which now doesn't seem to exist anymore.
>
> At the moment, the direct link to the old downloads page
>   (https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) is not
>   yet set to redirect, so it is still possible to access that page, but
>   indeed that page is considered deprecated in favor of the open source
>   continuous builds archive at this time, and the previous versions
>   provided on that page are from the earlier Xamarin 15.5 Release rather
>   than the Xamarin 15.6 Release.

Comment: Hey lain Smith you save my day. This is what I was expected. Great. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 11):

You could also look for versions listed at the [brew repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/commits/master/Casks/visual-studio.rb).

Use the url pattern `https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-{version}.dmg`.

Comment: This is useful. I had assumed that older version of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac would be included with older version of VS for Mac. But that's not the case. I had to download the older versions separately from this link: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios

Hope someone finds this useful.