# Need to download specific preview version of Visual studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I need to test a MAUI app in iPad with iOS version - 15.7. for which I need a VS for Mac preview version which is compatible with Xcode version - 13.4.1. I couldn't find the link of it. How to find the exact download link ?

I have tried with multiple links as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409042/need-lower-version-of-visual-studio-for-mac?newreg=9a949436441241a2a482d2f6c5d6d92e) but couldn't found exact version (any preview version released in may 2022)